# Change TColor property over a procedure delphi ( Doesn't Work )

Tags: delphi

Someone can explain me why the option *1 doesn't work? Tks

I put here a simple code because I would like understand why the code doesn't accept I pass the TColor like instruction in a procedure

```
procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
  procedure ChangeColor( Value : TColor );
  begin
     //*1
     Value := clRed;
  end;
begin
   //*1 IT DOESN'T WORK
   ChangeColor( Edit1.Color );
   ChangeColor( ComboBox1.Color );

//----------------------------------//

   //*2 IT WORKS
   Edit1.Color := clRed;
   ComboBox1.Color := clRed;
end;
```

Thank You

Comment: You need to familiarize yourself with by-value vs. by-reference parameters.

Comment: @KenWhite, no, it is relevant (the other thing is what it will bring a compiler error due read-write property instead of silently doing nothing)

Comment: @KenWhite, not really. One simply does nothing due erroneous by-value parameter. This is a core problem with OP's attempt to extract the statement to procedure.

Comment: .. and later by property setters. Setting Color does not only modify FColor. It would be easier if you told why do you think it should work.

Comment: @Francisco You say: "It doesn't work", but you fail to explain the behaviour you're expecting.

Comment: @Craig - See the code for the expected behavior, it commented with //*2

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a problem description.

Comment: Never mind - I figured something else out :)

Comment: @Michael - About what?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I made a comment I wanted to unmake - I couldn't see how to delete the comment and an comment must be so long.  Please ignore. Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option 1 does not work because the code does not attempt to assign anything to the `Color` property of your controls. It just passes a color value to the nested procedure `ChangeColor`. And the only thing the nested procedure does is to assign a value to the passed parameter.

If you expect that the parameter you passed to a procedure is modified after the procedure returns read about [variable parameters](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Parameters_(Delphi)#Value_and_Variable_Parameters).

If you expect that the colors of the controls should be changed in the nested procedure itself, additionally read about [properties](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Properties).

Comment: Your solution about using var parameter passed to the function will not work because Color in OP case is a property and not an existing variable.

Comment: @Silver - What solution are you talking about? I just answered the question and explained why the code did not work. Then linked two documentation topics for the OP to make progress - which "properties" is one. I suggest you to read an answer before downvoting.

Answer (score 3):

A workaround for the limitations noted by Sertac would be to use a `function` instead of a `procedure`:

```
procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);

  function ChangeColor: TColor;
  begin
     Result := clRed;
  end;

begin
   Edit1.Color := ChangeColor;
   ComboBox1.Color := ChangeColor;
end;
```

I assume the reason that you want to use a procedure rather than assigning a constant is due to more complex logic than shown.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to work With RTTI :

```
uses System.TypInfo;

procedure UpdateColorProperty(Ctrl : TControl; const aColor : Tcolor);
var PropInfo : PPropinfo;
begin
  if aColor = clNone then Exit;
  if Assigned(Ctrl) then begin
    PropInfo := GetPropInfo(Ctrl, 'Color');
    if PropInfo <> nil then
      SetPropValue(Ctrl, 'Color', aColor);
  end;
end;
```